# mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0

Tags: linux, fedora

According [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-cdrom-in-linux) instruction I tried to mount DVD disk into Fedora 24

What I did.

```
[root@mic3ael mic3ael]#  wodim --devices 
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sr0'  rwrw-- : 'HL-DT-ST' 'DVDRAM GUC0N'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

According to output, I understood that `/dev/sr0` should be mounted

```
[root@mic3ael mic3ael]# mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /media/cdrom
mount: /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

but the DVD didn't mount.

The question is what does it mean

```
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

and how to mount DVD disk into Fedora 24.

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: Did you actually put a DVD disk in the drive?

Comment: Insert DVD disk and mounted automatically.Or mounted manually without -t should work.Like DVD movies are not ISO format.

Comment: Yes, I put DVD disk in the drive.

Comment: @MichaelHorojanski did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: I didn't, find a solution.

Comment: Have you got [libdvdcss](https://download.videolan.org/pub/libdvdcss/last/) installed?